# Rotating the Android app while posting comment crashes the app

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app

App version: 1.0.31/1.0.35/1.0.52
Device: Nexus 7
Problem: When you rotate the screen while passing a comment the app will crash. The comment is still posted, even though the app does crash.
LOGCAT:

```
04-27 01:59:20.562 E/AndroidRuntime(17551): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 01:59:20.562 E/AndroidRuntime(17551): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
04-27 01:59:20.562 E/AndroidRuntime(17551):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:406)
04-27 01:59:20.562 E/AndroidRuntime(17551):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:308)
04-27 01:59:20.562 E/AndroidRuntime(17551):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:79)
04-27 01:59:20.562 E/AndroidRuntime(17551):     at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:323)
04-27 01:59:20.562 E/AndroidRuntime(17551):     at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:306)
04-27 01:59:20.562 E/AndroidRuntime(17551):     at com.stackexchange.marvin.core.OperationThatCanFail$1.onPostExecute(OperationThatCanFail.java:81)
04-27 01:59:20.562 E/AndroidRuntime(17551):     at com.stackexchange.marvin.core.OperationThatCanFail$1.onPostExecute(OperationThatCanFail.java:67)
04-27 01:59:20.562 E/AndroidRuntime(17551):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
04-27 01:59:20.562 E/AndroidRuntime(17551):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-27 01:59:20.562 E/AndroidRuntime(17551):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
04-27 01:59:20.562 E/AndroidRuntime(17551):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-27 01:59:20.562 E/AndroidRuntime(17551):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-27 01:59:20.562 E/AndroidRuntime(17551):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-27 01:59:20.562 E/AndroidRuntime(17551):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 01:59:20.562 E/AndroidRuntime(17551):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-27 01:59:20.562 E/AndroidRuntime(17551):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-27 01:59:20.562 E/AndroidRuntime(17551):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-27 01:59:20.562 E/AndroidRuntime(17551):     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
04-27 01:59:20.562 E/AndroidRuntime(17551):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `at com.stackexchange.marvin.core.OperationThatCanFail$1.onPostExecute(OperationThatCanFail.java:81)` rofl, I think they meant for the app to crash on that. ;)

Comment: The title doesn't match the content of your question (question vs. comment).

Comment: Do you use the default Android keyboard?

Comment: Yes I do use the default keyboard

Comment: This is still happening in version 1.0.35. The comment is still posted even with the crash happening.

Comment: Testing to see if this happens...and it does still happen, but still posted the comment.

Comment: Repro'd on Nexus 4, 5.0.1 Lollipop, app v1.0.52. Looking from `onPostExecute`, it must be using `AsyncTask`, and yes, this must be handled carefully if there is configuration change (e.g. orientation change) since the app might lose the reference to the task and crash.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this! Sorry it took so long to fix, but it's fixed as of the next beta update (version 1.0.53+).

Technical details: 
Oh the irony of `OperationThatCanFail` causing a crash... here's the diff on `onPostExecute`:

```java
             protected void onPostExecute(Exception e) {
+                if (fragment != null) {
+                    fragment.removeDependentAsyncTask(this);
+                    if (fragment.isDetached())
+                        return;
+                }
                 if (mDia != null && mDia.isShowing())
                     mDia.dismiss();
-                if (fragment != null)
-                    fragment.removeDependentAsyncTask(this);
                 if (isCancelled())
                     return;
                 if (e != null) { onFailure(e); } else { onSuccess(); }
             }
```

A fragment being "detached" (removed from the window manager) automatically removes all the children views in it from the manager so we needed to check if it was detached before trying to kill the status indicator pop-up.